# How to check child node in javascript

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'm trying to  apply custom style from links in my blog.

I need to check if `<a>` node have a direct `<img>` node for not apply the style in this case, but I don't know how to do.

this is my js function

```
function linkify( selector ) {
    var nodes = document.querySelectorAll( selector );
    for( var i = 0, len = nodes.length; i < len; i++ ) {
        var node = nodes[i];
        var child=(node.firstElementChild||node.firstChild);

        if( !node.className || !node.className.match( /roll/g )) {
            // check that not it tag link and 'read more' button link
            // TODO: Check that not have a img node!
            if((node.getAttribute('rel') != 'tag') && (node.getAttribute('class') != 'more-link')) {
                node.className += ' roll';
            node.innerHTML = '<span data-title="'+ node.text +'">' + node.innerHTML + '</span>';
        }
    } } }

jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
    linkify('.post-content p a');

});
```

Comment: Why don't you use jquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you're using jQuery at the bottom of your code block, so I'll give you a jQuery answer as it is simpler, let me know if you need a pure javascript solution:

```
if($(node).children('a').length > 0){
     //If true, your node as a child <a> element
}
```

Comment: No exactly, but thanks for the idea. I have used `node.children[0]` to check it. Now, how I check that the children is a `img` tag?

Comment: I might be misunderstanding, you need to know if the node has a `img` child?